# My function is not working on my own stack implementation in Python

Tags: stack, python-3.6

I have implemented a stack and created a function balance check that given a string of opening and closing parentheses, check whether it’s balanced or not. For example ‘([])’ is balanced but ‘([)]’ is not.
The code for my stack implementation is :

```
class Stack(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items) - 1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

The code for balance_check function is:

```
def balance_check1(s):

    if len(s) % 2 != 0:
        return False

    opening = set("([{")

    matching = ([("( "," )"),("[","]"),("{","}")])

    stack = Stack()

    for paren in s:

        if paren in opening:
            stack.push(paren)

        else:

            if stack.size() == 0:
                return False

            last_open = stack.pop()

            if (last_open,paren) not in matching:
                return False

    return stack.size() == 0
```

When I run my function with the Python's list it runs fine but when i use my own stack it gives wrong output.

Comment: What's your input, the current output and the expected output?

Comment: This might be part of the problem: `("( "," )")` you have whitespace in your strings here.

Comment: my current output for test case balance_check([({})]) is false whereas the expected output is true.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh has already provided with the solution in the above comment. And also make sure you're passing strings encapsulated within inverted commas. That is `balance_check("[({})]")`, not `balance_check([({})])`

Comment: @Patrick Haugh Thanks Haugh